# I want to create a animation on google map,move from one location to another

Tags: google-maps, animation, gps

i know the different locations' gps ,how i could create this animation?and i try to convert the gps to offset ,but i failed.so ,who could give me a point to solve the problem,thanks

```
GMSPolyline *polyline = [[GMSPolyline alloc] init];
    GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];
    [path addCoordinate:kSanLiTun];
    [path addCoordinate:kLongZe];
    [path addCoordinate:kJinTai];
    polyline.path = path;
    polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
    polyline.strokeWidth = 2.f;
    polyline.zIndex = 15;  // above the larger geodesic line
    polyline.map = self.mapView;
```

this code to draw three lines from location.i want to create animation could make a picture move on the line